# loopback offline sync in an Ionic2 client

Tags: angular, ionic2, synchronization, offline, loopback

I am developing a Hybrid Mobile Application using loopback3 & Ionic2 with loopback SDK builder.

**Background:** 
The application contains a server/API module generated using the Loopback CLI and a client module generated using the Ionic2 CLI. The client makes use of the Angular2 models and services generated by the Loopback SDK builder.(available at https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder)

I am now working to integrate offline synchronization into my client application using the loopback Offline sync example created for AngularJS. (available at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-offline-sync)

**The problem:** 
I am faced with the following issues when integrating the offline sync folder (lbclient) with loopback SDK builder code.

1. How to integrate the separate models of lbclient & loopback SDK?
2. How to incorporate the replication.js files present in the lbclient/boot folder into the application?
3. Where to place the browser.bundle.js file in the application?

Is this the best strategy?
Did anybody happen to run through these challenges?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am a core member of LoopBack team and a co-author of our Offline Sync implementation.*

Hello, I am afraid LoopBack's offline synchronization is currently not compatible with client SDKs like LoopBack SDK builder. The offline synchronization leverages LoopBack's server runtime in the browser, combining "memory" connector to store the data locally in the browser (local) storage, "remote" connector to talk to the remote server and a change replication algorithm to synchronize these two datasources.

You can find a bit more details in the talk I gave at NodeConf One-shot London and Budapest in 2014 ([slides](https://www.slideshare.net/Bajtos/2014-07offline-data-sync-in-loop-back), [video recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upuUTQS2DXw)) and our [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Synchronization.html).

While it should be possible to implement a client for our change replication protocol in LoopBack SDK Builder, it would require a non-trivial effort.